# jQuery UI modal-dialog: Prevent keypressed when dialog is open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, event-handling, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jquery-ui modal and my application uses a couple of hotkeys bound to modal-dialogs.

Here is my working [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NcM9K/4/) and code:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){console.log("pressed a key: " + e.which);})
var dialog = $('#modal-dialog')
    .dialog({ modal: true, autoOpen: false, buttons: [{text:"ok"}] });
    .keypress(function(e){console.log("cought!"); e.stopPropagation()})
$("#bt").click(function(){dialog.dialog("open")})
```

When a modal dialog is open, it is supposed to suppress the keypressed events from traveling up the Dom-tree to the document/window.
when an input element has focus (does not work with a button) stopPropagation kicks in.
otherwise however event is propagated.

What is the best way to resolve this?

Comment: The thing I noticed is that keydown, keyup and keypress events are usually blocked by the modal dialog, but if RETURN or ESCAPE cause the dialog to close then the KEYUP event gets triggered in the DOM because the dialog closes on the KEYDOWN event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once opened, the element the dialog widget is created from apparently is removed from the DOM tree and jQuery inserts a fresh element accessible by the dialogs widget-method.
The element is the one that needs to stop propagation.
Anyway, technically also the modal overlay will have to be considered.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){console.log("pressed a key: " + e.which);})
var dialog = $('#modal-dialog')
    .dialog({ modal: true, autoOpen: false, buttons: [{text:"ok"}] });
$("#bt").click(function(){
    dialog.dialog("open")
    .dialog("widget")
    .keydown(function(e){console.log("cought!"); e.stopPropagation()})
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `unbind` `$(document).keypress` event when dialog is open and again `bind` `$(document).keypress` when dialog closes.

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/NcM9K/6/)**

js code:

```
function bind_event()
{
    $(document).keypress(function(e){console.log("pressed a key: " + e.which);});
}
function unbind_event()
{
    $(document).unbind('keypress');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    bind_event();

var dialog = $('#modal-dialog')
    .dialog({ 
        modal: true, autoOpen: false, buttons: [{text:"ok"}],
        open: function( event, ui ) {
            unbind_event();
            /*$(document).keypress(function(e){
                console.log('dialog open '+e.which);
            });*/
        },
        close: function( event, ui ) {
            bind_event();
        }
    })
    .keypress(function(e){
        console.log("cought!"); 
        e.stopPropagation()
    })
$("#bt").click(function(){dialog.dialog("open")});
});
```

Comment: With this approach I would have to temporarily save the function bound to keypress so that it can be bound again, when the dialog closes.
Does that work without a problem?